# Чем различаются методы createRoot() и makeRoot() в Nested Sets?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Использую плагин nested sets для symfony 1.4 (ORM Doctrine).

Answer (score 1):

makeRoot() - создает из **существующего** раздела root ("перемещает")

createRoot() - создает **новый** root раздел.